# MongoDB maximum "$in" operator match values

Tags: mongodb

Does anyone know if MongoDB has any limits on the number of matches that can be specified with an "$in" operator?

For example,

```
db.inventory.find( { _id: { "$in": [ "abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu", "vwx", "yz" ] } } )
```

That "$in" match array has 9 strings.

Can I have 20, 30, a hundred, or even a thousand array items with an "$in" operator specifier query?  Obviously performance can be effected by doing huge queries, but just wondering if MongoDB would produce an error if the "$in" match is a huge array.

Thanks.

Ps- My question is regarding the query itself, not how many results are returned.

Comment: Thank you. This was difficult to search for an answer, because the word "in" is too common.

Answer (score 2):

The only "limit" imposed is the [BSON limit which is 16MB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size) for the total document, which is both the combined query content and the command instruction to be sent over the wire to the server. So it's not just the size of `$in` arguments, but also a factor of their "type" and the other query components and command components themselves. The latter part being relatively small.

Any other limitation will be in the way that "arrays" are handled by your native language implementation, which may impose it's own limit on the number of elements.

Naturally though, managing "long lists" for matching in any code is usually cumbersome and not great for performance, so you should be aware that there is likely to be a point where better performance would be achieved by "limiting" your `$in` to smaller chunks of the list rather than all at once.

Where possible, as a "rule of thumb", try to keep to about 300 entries per request. You could likely throw a lot more, but it is also a number of "arguments" that marries up with the parameter restrictions of several SQL database solutions. As such then such "limits" are generally applied on par.

Comment: How did you reach to a conclusion about _300 entries per request_? Why is 300?